# WinRAR extracted a folder ending in in a . and this has confused Windows immensely

Tags: windows, winrar

Because of the name of the folder is more than slightly suggestive (and my inability to interact with said folder whatsoever to rename it), I'd rather not take a screenshot, but I just extracted a rar file where one of the folders contained within ended in a full stop, which seems to have confused windows into believing the files do not exist. The folder is, effectively, corrupt. I have properly gone into the offending rar, removed the appropriate fullstops and extracted the contents properly thereafter, but I'm still left with 2 ghost folders I cannot get rid of, not even with command prompt (I say two because I extracted a second time not realising there was a second folder within the first.)

Comment: Have you tried using the Move command to rename the folder?  ie: `move "c:\folderName." "c:\folderName"`?  Or perhaps with the 8.3 file name: `move "c:\folder~1" "c:\folderName"`?

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified, 0 items moved", both with or without the 8.3 name

Comment: Have you tried using [rmdir](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rmdir.mspx?mfr=true) with a wildcard for the offending directory name, e.g. `rmdir abc* /s`?

Comment: ...or using a UNC path like `\\?\C:\user\docs\abc.`?

Comment: What I did was a bit more reckless, but it did work regardless, thanks Andrew. I moved everything aside from the 2 offending folders out of the folder they're in and completely wiped the directory with rd /s /q - admittedly, very dangerous if I weren't paying attention, but the issue is now resolved.